# Как вернуть несколько самых длинных слов из строки?

Tags: javascript

Вот функция которая принимает строку и возвращает самое длинное слово в этой строке.

Если будет два слова одинаковой длинны, вернётся первое. Как реализовать, чтобы возвращались все самые длинные слова?

```
const findLongestWord = function(string) {
    return string.split(' ').sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const words = 'ads da sd sad as das das s sd';

const findLongestWord = function(string) {
  const sortStr = string.split(' ').sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length);
  return sortStr.filter((el) => el.length === sortStr[0].length);
};

console.log(findLongestWord(words));
```